# If empty condition behaviour

Tags: bash, shell, grep

What is the difference between:

```
if echo " T " | grep -q " F "; then echo FOUND; else echo NOT; fi
```

And:

```
if ""; then echo FOUND; else echo NOT; fi
```

The output of first command is:

```
NOT
```

The output of second command is:

```
: command not found 
NOT
```

Both should behave in the same way, I think.

Comment: an empty command is not the same as a command that give true/false.

Comment: @Archemar output of the grep command is empty!

Comment: do not mistake output and return code. true/false return nothing, but a return code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
: command not found
```

This means that the command provided as condition in the if statement is not found. That command `""` is just an empty string and therefore not found; there is no such command.

According to the manual page of bash, the syntax of an if statement should look as follows:

```
if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi
```

> A **list** is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the
>   operators ;, &, &&, or ||, and optionally terminated by one of ;, &,
>   or .

So, in the if statement above the list is executed and an exit code of 127 came back and an error is trown that the command is not found. This is then evaluated as false, therefore the else block is executed.

---

What you may want is something as follows:

```
if false; then echo FOUND; else echo NOT; fi
```

Comment: ` exit code of 127 came back` how does one know exit code of a statement's execution? Is it possible to print exit code of `echo " T " | grep -q " F "`?

Comment: @user13107 Yes, right after execution of the command in a shell, use `echo $?` to print the exit status. This is what the if clause evaluates to determine whether the if or the else block is executed.